# Keeping the section 1 active on page refresh(Javascript + css)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Iv got 3 buttons and 3 hidden sections:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ug5Qf.jpg)

Once i click on a button the sections goes from hidden to shown:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lC4hO.jpg)

But i need the section 1 to be displayed as shown as default on page refresh.

script iv got right now:

```
<script>
var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
var btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");
var btn3 = document.getElementById("btn3");

btn1.onclick = function(event){
event.preventDefault();
toggleDivs("sect1");
};
btn2.onclick = function(event){
event.preventDefault();
toggleDivs("sect2");
};
btn3.onclick = function(event){
event.preventDefault();
toggleDivs("sect3");
};

function toggleDivs(s){
//reset
document.getElementById("sect1").classList.remove("shown");
document.getElementById("sect2").classList.remove("shown");
document.getElementById("sect3").classList.remove("shown");
//show
document.getElementById(s).classList.add("shown");
}
</script>
<style>
.elementor-editor-active .hidden{
display:block;
}
.hidden{
display:none;
}
.shown{
display: block !important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the section one 'active' once the page is loaded. You can do it via JS or CSS also.

```
<script>
var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
var btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");
var btn3 = document.getElementById("btn3");

btn1.onclick = function(event){
event.preventDefault();
btn1.classList.add("active-btn"); // add active class
btn2.classList.remove("active-btn"); // remove from other btn
btn3.classList.remove("active-btn"); // remove from other btn
toggleDivs("sect1");
};
btn2.onclick = function(event){
event.preventDefault();
btn2.classList.add("active-btn");// add active class
btn1.classList.remove("active-btn"); // remove from other btn
btn3.classList.remove("active-btn"); // remove from other btn
toggleDivs("sect2");
};
btn3.onclick = function(event){
event.preventDefault();
btn3.classList.add("active-btn"); // add active class
btn1.classList.remove("active-btn"); // remove from other btn
btn2.classList.remove("active-btn"); // remove from other btn
toggleDivs("sect3");
};

function toggleDivs(s){
//reset
document.getElementById("sect1").classList.remove("shown");
document.getElementById("sect2").classList.remove("shown");
document.getElementById("sect3").classList.remove("shown");
//show
document.getElementById(s).classList.add("shown");
}

 
// Once everything is ready
toggleDivs("sect1"); // call it with default activated session
// if you want to load data from API then wait before calling this function. 


</script>
<style>
.elementor-editor-active .hidden{
display:block;
}
.hidden{
display:none;
}
.shown{
display: block !important;
}
// add class for active button
.active-btn{
   color:red;
   background: white;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Oh yes it worked! Do you know if i can toggle the buttons with colors once they are active? 
So once active = text color = pink e.g
once not active = text color = black e.g

Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Yeah , I think, you can add another class while activating the element 

document.getElementById(s).classList.add("red");

and add css 
.red{ color:red}

don't forgot to remove it while deactivating the item.

Comment: Not sure where to add it? Im very new to JS so im sorry for not understanding you. 
And you want me to specificy the button with css right?

Comment: I make it simple, added more property in .show class in css section, since this class is getting toggled on active button. It will reflect as well.

Comment: It changed the elements text color, not the button hmm..

Comment: I got you wrong on the 1st place. My bad, updated the css for active button. It will be same as section toggle.

Comment: No problem, im copying stright away right now because im not understanding the comments? Do you want me to delte the lines with comments: "//Remove from... "

Comment: That's required to remove the added class. That's just a comment.

Comment: I mean iv copied all of this, but it still doesnt effect the color of the button once its active :p